# Rails 3 - Different Devise Options for the first User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I'm using Devise in my Rails 3.0.10 app where the `Users` that sign up must reply to the email Devise generates automatically.

But I wonder, how can I make Devise ignore this option for the first user that will sign up, and request email confirmation for the *n* next users?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think for a good reason to do this. Normally the first user is the administrator (or the owner) and he/she should never have to register. What I usually do is create the first user through a seed:

```
# db/seeds.rb
...
User.create!(email: "first@user.com", password: "YayIAm1AndHaveADifficultPassword")
...
```

Then when I have to deploy (this probably will go into capistrano but anyway) you run:

```
rake db:seed
```

This way you don't have to hack Devise to not to send the first user a confirmation e-mail.